# How to Web Scrap from a Website that Randomly Generates Html Information upon being Opened with a Browser?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

```
def main(url):
   
    # content of URL
    r = requests.get(url)
 
    # Parse HTML Code
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
 
    print(soup.find_all('h1')
)
```

This code gets the html from a website using the Beautiful Soup Library & narrows it down. It returns:

```
[<h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title" id="ticker">Loading...</h1>]
```

When the website is opened in a browser, it has a random Ticker Symbol located in that line of html. However, when code is used to get the html, it has the word "Loading..." instead.

How do I use code to extract the randomly generated ticker symbol when opening the site?

I was expecting to get a random ticker symbol as one does when the website is opened normally. The website I am attempting to scrap is url = "https://www.rayberger.org/random-stock-picker/"

Comment: BS4 is not your tool. It is going to get a version of the site that one would get doing a view source on the page. i.e. one where the javascript has not been run. You need somehting more like `selenium`

Answer (score 1):

The page loads the symbol via JavaScript from external URL (in fact, loads the whole array of symbols and then uses javascript to print random symbol), so `beautifulsoup` doesn't see the ticker symbol.

You can simulate this with this example:

```py
import random

import requests

url = "https://www.rayberger.org/random-stock-picker/stocks.json"
data = requests.get(url).json()
print(random.choice(data))
```

Prints (for example):

```
FVE
```